# If a timestamp is anchored in UTC, why isn't Python's `fromtimestamp` timezone-aware?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, timezone

**To my knowledge:**
Python's `datetime` can be "naive" (if no timezone-info is available) or "timezone-aware". In contrast, a timestamp is well-defined to be anchored in UTC, i.e. a timestamp `0` corresponds to `1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00` (no matter of your location).

**Question:** Why does `datetime.fromtimestamp()` return a naive `datetime` object though it has a well-defined input?

**MWE**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

timestamp = 0

# output: "1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00", i.e. providing the timezone information,
# the resulting datetime is timezone-aware and accurate
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=timezone.utc))

# output: "1970-01-01 01:00:00" (for me running it in CET+0100 timezone), i.e.
# the interpretation is aware of my local time shift, but the resulting datetime
# is naive though it could be timezone-aware and thus not well-defined anymore
# 
# I would have wished for/expected: "1970-01-01 01:00:00+01:00"
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp))
```

**Why do I care?**
The point is that we loose information in a dangerous way, i.e. we switch from a well-defined object to an object that is only well-defined if we know the timezone of the PC it has been read in. Though it could do better, imo. The way it is implemented, it is easy to mess things up without recognizing it.

But maybe I got the whole concept wrong :) That is why I am asking...

Comment: Would you have asked the same question if naive datetime would resemble UTC? Still without the leap seconds maybe but something less squishy than "local time"?

Comment: I assume the concept here is convenience and consistency over unambiguousness. `fromtimestamp` gives something convenient, something the user might be accustomed to - think about UTC offsets not as in the UK or Central Europe. `datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp).timestamp()` is a consistent round-trip, so you don't 'loose' any information in that sense.

Comment: @FObersteiner That is part of my point: `datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp).timestamp()` is not a consistent round-trip if you run one part at one and one on another PC located in different time zones. First, that sounds constructed, but what if you run into the easy-to-make mistake to represent the timestamp as naive datetime in a database if you don't recognize the details happening under the hood of timestamp-datetime conversion (e.g., who would expect that it uses the local timezone though this is not even possible to query from `datetime` library) - sufficiently confusing.

Comment: That does not sound constructed to me, I've been there ;-) And sufficiently confusing that there are probably a hundred or more questions here on SO around this problem. What I meant to point out was that the developers of Python made a choice, and that tolerates such ambiguity. Consistency is also limited to a certain "frame" (all on one machine etc.) i.e. only valid under certain assumptions, that's correct.

Comment: @FObersteiner That they-did-it-like-that argument is quite disarming, I have to admit :) Still, there are cases where it is just a matter of choice; and there are cases of design bugs. To my understanding it is the second, because if you have the local timezone under the hood available and even use it for conversion, why would you withdraw this. So my question seems to be: Am I wrong? Maybe there *is* a reason for this design. E.g., because the function does not really use a local timezone, but something like a current UTC-offset that may change with seasons, or anything else that I don't see.

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer a good reasoning over "they-did-it-like-that", and I think there is a history to "that". I started using Python when 3.6 was just out, so rather late in the history of the language, but I think time zone handling was something that came in rather late as well. I mean, it took until 3.9 until the standard library was able to handle "real" time zones (implement IANA tz database rules). Excited to see if somebody wants to provide a comprehensive answer to this. @MattJohnson-Pint maybe, or @MarkRansom?